# How to include a variable in REGEX in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to python, and really new to regex!

I am using the re module in python and trying to insert a variable into a re.compile statement.

I have a file that includes these words as test - linux windows mac -

So if I do `re.compile('...u.', re.IGNORECASE)` it will find linux.

But how to I put `...u.` into a variable to use in the re.compile? Just assigning `'...u.'` to a variable and putting that in place of it in the re.compile does not seem to work.

I found on another thread something about the `%` character, but could not get that to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show your code snippet for "assigning `'...u.'` to a variable"?

It works for me:

```
import re
str = 'linux windows mac'
a = re.compile('...u.',re.IGNORECASE)
a.match(str).group(0) # returns 'linux'

regex = '...u.'
b = re.compile(regex,re.IGNORECASE)
b.match(str).group(0) # returns 'linux'
```

Comment: There was the problem. I was putting double quotes around it. So I had `regex = "'...u.'"` thinking that I needed to do that so it would include the single quotes when assigning it to the variable. Thank you so much!